# Proof of Theorem: Zeros of $\sinh z$ and $\cosh z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove the following theorem:

> The zeros of $\sinh z$ and $\cosh z$ in the complex plane all lie on the imaginary axis. To be specific
>   $$\sinh z=0$$ if and only if $z=n\pi i$   $(n=0,\pm1,2,...)$
>   and$$\cosh z=0$$ if and only if $z=(\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi)i$   $(n=0,\pm1,\pm2,...)$.

I know $\sinh z = \frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}$ and $\cosh z = \frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2}$, but where to from here?

Comment: Just plug it in, multiply by $e^z$

Comment: Hint: $\sinh(z)=i\sin(iz)$ and $\cosh(z)=\cos(iz)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\sinh z = \frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}=0\iff e^z-\frac{1}{e^z}=0\iff e^{2z}=1\iff 2z=i(0+2\pi k) \iff z=ik\pi$$
Remain details.

Answer (score 1):

$e^x$ is never $0$... So... $e^x\pm e^{-x}=0\iff e^x(e^x\pm e^{-x})=0\iff e^{2x}\pm 1=0.$